# list-style-image bullet displaying out of place

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to make a sidebar navigation list containing another list whose contents show/hide when clicked.  For the `li` containing the collapsible list, I put in a custom `list-style-image` (actually, two that are toggled between with JS when clicked.)  The problem is that the custom image is rendering on the edge of the page instead of in line where a regular bullet point would be.  The image has a transparent background, so that's not the problem.  Maybe it's something with how I floated the `div` to the left?
Here's my HTML and CSS and a screenshot of how it's displaying.

Code snippets (css/html):

```css
    #sidebar{
      position: fixed;
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      background-color: green;
    }

    #main{
      float: right;
      width: 75%;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    #songs{
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .song{
      list-style: decimal;
    }

    .songclosed{
      display: none;
    }

    .closed{
      list-style-image: url("../images/closed.png");
    }

    .open{
      list-style-image: url("../images/open.png");
    }
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>Home</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="info.html">Info</a>
        </li>
        <li id="openclose" class="closed" onclick="openclose()">
          <p id="songs">Songs</p>
          <ol>
            <li class="song songclosed">
              <a href="#">Song 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="song songclosed">
              <a href="#">Song 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="song songclosed">
              <a href="#">Song 3</a>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

[Image--See the little black triangle on the left?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxzR3.png)

I've tried `list-style-position: inside` and `overflow: hidden`.  Both made a difference, but neither worked properly.

Final note: The images are bigger (100x100) than a regular bullet point so that may be a slight problem, but I can edit them down and see what changes if someone can tell me how big a regular bullet is.

Comment: Those list-style properties give you rather little control; it often works better if you use a pseudo element instead - that you can format and position however you like.

Comment: @misorude Yeah, I ended up just making a table and it turned out [pretty well](https://i.imgur.com/3AEgVPS.png).  A little more styling should perfect it.